# How to end a 2D char array when string is '\0'?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, char, c-strings

I have a program that queries the user for string inputs that are stored in a 2D char array. The program should stop asking for inputs when 20 strings are entered or when the user hits enter twice.

For some reason no matter what I do, the program will keep displaying all empty strings even though the user hasn't populated them. How can I stop this?

```
int main()
{
    char sentences[20][81] = { '\0' };

    cout << "Enter up to 20 sentences - when done, Press ENTER: ";
    input(sentences);

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        if (sentences[i] == '\0' || sentences[i] == "\n")
            break;
        else
        {
            cout << "\nHere is sentence " << i + 1 << ": " << endl << sentences[i] << endl;
            menu(sentences[i]);
        }

    }

    cout << "\nPress any key to continue...";
    _getch();
    return 0;
}

void input(char str[20][81])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        cin.getline(str[i], 81, '\n');
        if (str[i][0] == '\0')
            break;
    }
}
```

There are no error messages, and I expect that the check here

```
if (sentences[i] == '\0' || sentences[i] == "\n"
    break;
```

should end the program when a blank c-string is encountered, why isn't that happening?

Comment: By using `std::vector<std::string>` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This check here is wrong:

```
if (sentences[i] == '\0' || sentences[i] == "\n")
```

You're comparing `sentences[i]` (a `char*`) with `'\0'` (a `char`). The `sentences[i] == "\n"` part is entirely wrong - just get rid of that. Your check should look like this:

```
if (sentences[i][0] == '\0' )
```

But I would really recommend just using a `std::vector<std::string>` instead of this multidimensional c-style string construct. You can just use `push_back` to add a string to the vector and range-based for loop to go through the vector and print its results. You can do this with your `input` function like this:

```
void input(std::vector<std::string> &sentences)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        std::string s;
        std::getline(std::cin, s);
        if (s.empty())
            break;
        sentences.push_back(s);
    }
}
```

And then the `main` function like that:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> sentences;

    std::cout << "Enter up to 20 sentences - when done, Press ENTER: " << std::endl;
    input(sentences);

    for (int i = 0; i < sentences.size(); i++)
        std::cout << "Here is sentence " << i + 1 << ": " << std::endl << sentences[i] << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Press any key to continue...";

    //getch();
    return 0;
}
```

This way you wouldn't even need the hard-coded limit of `20` sentences, you could just remove it and have a `while (true)` loop instead.

Comment: Ah that's very interesting, and makes a lot of sense! I'll have to read up on what vector does, but I appreciate the added suggestion as I'd not even considered a different manner to approach it